# How to assign value to global variable in fetch method in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I am creating a react native app and I'm getting data from an API. I need to assign specific data into a global variable. That means my API return JSON data like {user_Id:"1' user_name:'abc' user_email:'abc@gmail.con'}. I need to assign user_Id into a global variable to access that in all of my screens.

**This is what I tried;**

```
componentDidMount() {
    const arrFinal = [];
    const {userDel} = this.state;
    fetch('my API url')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        // console.warn(responseJson);
        arrFinal.push(responseJson);
        arrFinal.map((item, index) => {
         global.UserID = item.user_Id
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
   console.error(global.UserID)
  }
```

But here nothing will print on console. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const arrFinal = [];
    const {userDel} = this.state;
    fetch('my API url')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        // console.warn(responseJson);
        arrFinal.push(responseJson);
        arrFinal.map((item, index) => {
         global.UserID = item.user_Id
         console.error(global.UserID)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
   // console.error(global.UserID)
  }
```

or :

```js
async componentDidMount() {
        const arrFinal = [];
    const { userDel } = this.state;
    const response = await fetch('my API url');
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    // console.warn(responseJson);
    arrFinal.push(responseJson);
    arrFinal.map((item, index) => {
      global.UserID = item.user_Id;
      console.error(global.UserID);
    });
    console.error(global.UserID);

  }
```

Comment: Nothing worked for me. It gives console.error: undefined

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem?